# A problem in a Question paper on Linear Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

anyone please solve it . Let the linear transformation $T: F^2\to F^3$ be defined by $T(x_1,x_2)=(x_1,x_1+x_2,x_2)$ . Then the nullity of T is

1. 0
2. 1
3. 2
4. 3

Also please mention how it is solved

Comment: Have you attempted anything?

Comment: I am confused how to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints: solve the linear system

$$\begin{cases}x_1=0\\{}\\x_1+x_2=0\\{}\\x_2=0\end{cases}$$

which is a rather trivial system. It's solution set's dimension is your map's nullity.

Comment: so I am confused that the answer is 0 or 1

Comment: What's the solution set of the above system? What is thus its dimension?

Comment: x_1=0 , x_2=0, thus the dim = 2

Comment: How in the world did you arrive to such a conclusion, @mahavir ?? Indeed, $\;x_1=x_2=0\;$ , but then this means the kernel of the map is **only** the zero vector and thus the nullity is zero!

Comment: actually I am confused in its concept. would you mind if I ask for the similar transformation but T(x1+x2)=(x1+2,x1+x2-3,x2-5), what would be then the nullity?

Comment: What you wrote is **not** a linear transformation, @mahavir...I think you should go back a read the basics carefully once more.

Comment: here is the point where I am getting confused how this happens , can you suggest me which book describes it well

Comment: Some ideas: Treil, "Linear Algebra Done Wrong" , Axler "Linear Algebra Done Right" , Shilov "Linear Algebra", etc.